# (:thumb) in Rails It does not load photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I use carieerwave and mini magick. I'm trying to scale pictures from carieerwave in the thumb version up to 500x250 but I can not read them:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3DAg.png)

Section with images (articles).  I can not set the same size of all photos (500x250) and when I add a version (: thumb) they will not load at all.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container" style="display: flex;">
        <% @posts.take(4).each do |post| %>
          <div class="carda" >
            <div class="card-content">
              <%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb), width: 500, height: 250), post %>
              <p class="title" style="margin-top: 5px; color:black">
      <%= raw link_to post.title, post  %>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And image uploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [500, 250]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

Comment: `post.image.url(:thumb)`

Comment: @Gabbar I changed to this line
              <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:thumb), width: 500, height: 250), post %> but still have this: https://i.imgur.com/BQ7Eiaa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
post.image.thumb.url
```

It should work

if you want it with inline styling try this:

```
<%= image_tag post.image.url, style: 'height:100px; width:100px;'%>
```

Comment: If you mean               <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.thumb.url), post %> its still not working :(

Comment: /edit wow <%= image_tag post.image.url, style: 'height:100px; width:100px;'%>
working, finally ;) thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) You must take care of the aspect ratio as well, either by managing this on ImageUploader resize_to_fit or just add width and height should be auto